# MySQL Certification Guide Practice Qn - Views' Column Names

Tags: mysql, sql, view

the question is

```
Which of the following methods for providing explicit names for the columns in a view work?

a. Include a column list
b. Provide column aliases in the view SELECT statement
c. Rename the columns when you select from the view
```

answer

```
a. Works: Include a column list
b. Works: Provide column aliases in the view SELECT statement
c. Does not work: Rename the columns when you select from the view
```

regarding (c) what do they mean by "Rename the columns when you select from the view"?

Comment: I cannot imagine what they mean here. Perhaps calling the columns by what you are wishing and hoping they would be? Running an `ALTER VIEW` statement prior to the column? I'm as curious as you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question in the certification guide is worded poorly.  You *can* give explicit names to columns when you select from a view, and this works:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT a, b, c FROM MyTable;
SELECT a AS d, b AS e, c AS f FROM MyView;
```

The problem is not with giving aliases to columns explicitly.  Here's the problem: if you rely on this instead of defining the view with distinct column names, and the view consists of a join such that the column names are ambiguous, you run into trouble:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS 
  SELECT m.a, m.b, m.c, o.a, o.b, o.c 
  FROM MyTable m JOIN OtherTable o;
```

This is not a valid view, because in the view definition, all column names must be distinct.  For instance, you would get ambiguous results when you query the view:

```
SELECT a FROM MyView;
```

Does this select the first `a` column or the second `a` column?

So you must have a distinct set of column names *in the view definition*, it's not enough to make them distinct as you query the view.

This is the reason I think the certification guide question was poorly worded.  It's not about renaming columns explicitly, it's about ensuring that the columns of the view have distinct names.  This is a common reason for renaming columns, so that's probably why the person writing the question wrote it that way.

---

Either of the other techniques mentioned in the question can resolve the ambiguity:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView (a, b, c, d, e, f) AS 
  SELECT m.a, m.b, m.c, o.a, o.b, o.c 
  FROM MyTable m JOIN OtherTable o;
```

or

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS 
  SELECT m.a, m.b, m.c, o.a AS d, o.b AS e, o.c AS f 
  FROM MyTable m JOIN OtherTable o;
```

Either way, you get the aliased columns:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView; -- returns result with columns a, b, c, d, e, f
```

Answer (score 0):

By "rename when you select" they surely mean something like `SELECT a AS b FROM theview` etc. The reason it doesn't work for the given task of "providing explicit names for the columns" is that there need not be an explicit, unambigous `a` in the view for you to "rename"... UNLESS you've already disambiguated by methods (a) or (b) [[in which case you may *also* "rename" this way, but that's pretty much a secondary issue!-)]].

Comment: i dont really get the part "is that there need not be an explicit, unambigous a in the view for you to "rename"... " is there a typo?

Comment: What I meant is: unless you do provide a `column_list`, or an `as` clause for every column in the `CREATE VIEW ... SELECT`, the names of the views' actual columns are not "explicit and unambiguous" (they're technically unambiguous because duplicates are not allowed, but not necessarily unambiguous to the reader).

Comment: hmm ... so its like using SELECT a AS b FROM theview is NOT "providing explicit names for the **VIEW'S** columns" but the "result set"'s columns